# What's the song that plays in FMA:Brotherhood episode 36 at 4:40?

Tags: music, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

There's a song in episode 36 of *Full Metal Alchemist: Brotherhood* at 4:40, and it plays many times afterward in that episode.

I listened to almost all of the soundtracks and could not find it.

What is this song?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for track 18, [No Answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HWefQC2xX4), from the Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood Original Soundtrack 2.